# Meteor stop template updating after onRendered

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Can Meteor stop a template from reactively updating itself after the initial render.

I have an app which displays images in a template. But I don't want any additional images that have been inserted into the collections to appear in the template unless the user does a reload.

In my template's helper I get the images by:

```
var usersImages = Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne: userID}},{ImagesUploaded: {$elemMatch: {editStatus:true}}}).fetch();
```

How can I now prevent further images being added to the template now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell your query to be non reactive by adding {reactive:false} as an option in the query

```
return var usersImages = Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne: userID}},{ImagesUploaded: {$elemMatch: {editStatus:true}},{reactive:false}}).fetch();
```

More info in the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find, (You can only use this client side)